# ¿Cómo unificar un array cuyo values son iguales en PHP?

Tags: php, array

Resulta que tengo este array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [question] => hola|hola?|hi|hello|buenas|buen dia|buenos dias
            [answer] => Hola, Buen dia
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [question] => hola|hola?|hi|hello|buenas|buen dia|buenos dias
            [answer] => Hola, como estas?
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [question] => hola|hola?|hi|hello|buenas|buen dia|buenos dias
            [answer] => Saludos, en que puedo ayudarte?
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [question] => hola|hola?|hi|hello|buenas|buen dia|buenos dias
            [answer] => Hola Amigo
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [question] => hola|hola?|hi|hello|buenas|buen dia|buenos dias
            [answer] => Hola, como te llamas
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [question] => ?|¿?
            [answer] => Deberia responder algo?
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [question] => ?|¿?
            [answer] => No soy adivino
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [question] => ?|¿?
            [answer] => No entiendo si solo colocas el signo '?'
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [question] => ?|¿?
            [answer] => Puedes ser mas especifico?
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [question] => eres real|eres un robot|eres un bot|eres humano|eres un programa|sos un programa|sos un robot|sos humano|sos humana|quien eres|que eres
            [answer] => Soy un robot
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [question] => eres real|eres un robot|eres un bot|eres humano|eres un programa|sos un programa|sos un robot|sos humano|sos humana|quien eres|que eres
            [answer] => Soy un programa
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [question] => eres real|eres un robot|eres un bot|eres humano|eres un programa|sos un programa|sos un robot|sos humano|sos humana|quien eres|que eres
            [answer] => Me han programado para ayudarte
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [question] => eres real|eres un robot|eres un bot|eres humano|eres un programa|sos un programa|sos un robot|sos humano|sos humana|quien eres|que eres
            [answer] => Si, soy una computadora chateando contigo
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [question] => eres real|eres un robot|eres un bot|eres humano|eres un programa|sos un programa|sos un robot|sos humano|sos humana|quien eres|que eres
            [answer] => No soy humano, eso es todo
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [question] => eres real|eres un robot|eres un bot|eres humano|eres un programa|sos un programa|sos un robot|sos humano|sos humana|quien eres|que eres
            [answer] => ChatBot suena como nombre humano?
        )

)
```

Y lo quiero convertir en esto:

```
Array
(
    [hola|hola?|hi|hello|buenas|buen dia|buenos dias] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hola, Buen dia
            [1] => Hola, como estas?
            [2] => Saludos, en que puedo ayudarte?
            [3] => Hola Amigo
            [4] => Hola, como te llamas
        )

    [?|¿?] => Array
        (
            [0] => Deberia responder algo?
            [1] => No soy adivino
            [2] => No entiendo si solo colocas el signo '?'
            [3] => Puedes ser mas especifico?
        )

    [eres real|eres un robot|eres un bot|eres humano|eres un programa|sos un programa|sos un robot|sos humano|sos humana|quien eres|que eres] => Array
        (
            [0] => Soy un robot
            [1] => Soy un programa
            [2] => Me han programado para ayudarte
            [3] => Si, soy una computadora chateando contigo
            [4] => No soy humano, eso es todo
            [5] => ChatBot suena como nombre humano?
        )

)
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente recorre el array y crea uno nuevo utilizando los datos del primero, `$value['question']` como clave y `$value['answer']` como valor.

Ejemplo:

```
$array = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'question' => 'hola|hola?|hi|hello|buenas|buen dia|buenos dias',
            'answer' => 'Hola, Buen dia'
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            'question' => 'hola|hola?|hi|hello|buenas|buen dia|buenos dias',
            'answer' => 'Hola, como estas?'
        ),

    2 => Array
        (
            'question' => 'hola|hola?|hi|hello|buenas|buen dia|buenos dias',
            'answer' => 'Saludos, en que puedo ayudarte?'
        ),
    3 => Array
        (
            'question' => '?|¿?',
            'answer' => 'Deberia responder algo?'
        ),
    4 => Array
        (
            'question' => '?|¿?',
            'answer' => 'No soy adivino'
        ),
);

$nuevoArray = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $nuevoArray[ $value['question'] ][] = $value['answer'];
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r($nuevoArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [hola|hola?|hi|hello|buenas|buen dia|buenos dias] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hola, Buen dia
            [1] => Hola, como estas?
            [2] => Saludos, en que puedo ayudarte?
        )

    [?|¿?] => Array
        (
            [0] => Deberia responder algo?
            [1] => No soy adivino
        )

)
```